# vs code: How to set chrome as the default browser instead of Edge?

Tags: browser, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to serve a React project live **on chrome**, but it always opens on Microsoft Edge.
Following some answers, I changed the settings like so:

```
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
"open-in-browser.default": "chrome"
```

But it still uses Edge.

Comment: what is the default browser in the system? Chrome or Edge?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi It wasn't set. It was solved after I set it to chrome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows actively "protects" the default app settings from change by anything but the end user.  [Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/0443cfca-c101-4985-b8ff-90fd1652e8fe/default-browser-userchoice-hashes-and-syncing-user-settings?forum=win10itprogeneral).

- The end user will need to change the default browser or application for type .html files
- or you will need to include instructions for the end user on how to do this.
- or you will need to include a small stub program that calls the Chrome executable with the html file as an argument, to launch the program.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much <3